# Update column to the COUNT of rows for specific values in another column. SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

My Table is:

```
|ID |data | cr |
| 1 | AAA |    |
| 2 | AAA |    |
| 3 | AAA |    |
| 4 | BBB |    |
| 5 | CCC |    |
| 6 | BBB |    |
```

I need result:

```
|ID |data | cr |
| 1 | AAA | 3  |
| 2 | AAA | 3  |
| 3 | AAA | 3  |
| 4 | BBB | 2  |
| 5 | CCC | 1  |
| 6 | BBB | 2  |
```

Found this  [Update a column value to the COUNT of rows for specific values in same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513726/update-a-column-value-to-the-count-of-rows-for-specific-values-in-same-table) and tried it:

```
UPDATE MyTbl a, 
        (SELECT data,COUNT(*) cnt 
            FROM MyTbl 
          GROUP BY data) b
    SET a.cr = b.cnt 
  WHERE a.data= b.data
```

SQL Server gives error :

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'a'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near 'b'.
```

Any idea how to do this in SQL Server (2014 Express).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `Update..set...from`. Try this one:

```
update a
set a.cr=b.cnt
from MyTbl a join
     (SELECT data,COUNT(*) cnt 
            FROM MyTbl 
          GROUP BY data) b on a.data=b.data
```

Result:

```
ID  data    cr
--------------
1   AAA     3
2   AAA     3
3   AAA     3
4   BBB     2
5   CCC     1
6   BBB     2
```

Demo in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/415502/1)

Comment: @StefanMichev: We have to be superfast ;)

Comment: Works, nice. This was fast. Thanks Bull:)

Comment: @Kaptah: See the demo added to the answer. Feel free to accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: May be we should use `COUNT(1)` instead of `COUNT(*)`. Anyway, great answer.

Comment: @Kartic: Thanks. BTW, `COUNT(1)` and `COUNT(*)` won't make any difference here. See [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
UPDATE t SET
    t.cr = vv.c
from MyTbl as t
left outer join 
(
    select count(*) as c , data from MyTbl group by data
) as vv on vv.data = t.data
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `count` with `window function` to find the count of each group. use this

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Count(1)OVER(partition BY data) AS crc,*
         FROM   MyTbl)
UPDATE cte
SET    cr = crc
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bc02f/6)

Comment: Nice that no additional join is added. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bc02f/6)

Comment: @ughai - Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SQL server 2014 version, I'd recommend Windowed function used inside a self join update query type syntax.

```
update a
set a.cr= b.v
from
(select id, count(1) over(partition by data order by data) as v from myTbl) b
join 
myTbl a on a.ID=b.id
-- now see the result here
select * from MyTbl
```

Sql fiddle for demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bc02f/4

Answer (score 0):

```
;with x as
 (
  SELECT Data , COUNT(*) AS cr
  FROM Table 
  GROUP BY Data
 )
UPDATE t
 SET t.cr = x.cr
FROM x INNER JOIN Table t ON x.data = t.data
```