# Oracle - Update COUNT of rows with specific value

Tags: oracle

This question has been posted several times but I am not able to get it work. I tried the approach mentioned in [Update column to the COUNT of rows for specific values in another column. SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072033/update-column-to-the-count-of-rows-for-specific-values-in-another-column-sql-se). It gives me **SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row** error not sure what I can do.

Below is my problem

```
UPDATE dataTable
 SET ACCX = (select b.cnt
               from dataTable a 
                 join
                (SELECT Account,
                       COUNT(1) cnt 
                  FROM  dataTable
                  GROUP BY Account) b 
                  on a.Account=b.Account)
        ,ACCR = 15481
        ,ACCF = 3
  WHERE ID = 1625
```

I only have the access & can change to the bold part since rest of the query is generated by the tool I cannot change it & I have to update ACCX column with the count of the value in column Account. Is it possible to do?

Note: - Account column is already populated with values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot follow that query because it is for sqlserver and NOT oracle.  It is simpler in oracle and does not need a join to itself.

This update will set the count for id 1625 only based on number of account numbers in datatable. See demo here; 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d154c/1

```
update dataTable a
set ACCR = 15481, 
    ACCF = 3, 
    a.ACCX = (
        select COUNT(*)
        from dataTable b
        where b.Account=a.Account)
WHERE a.ID = 1625;
```

Comment: Hi I get the below error. "ORA-00040: active time limit exceeded - call aborted" for 40K records. Please note that we cannot change any setting in Oracle server

Comment: I tried everything but cannot solve the error active time limit exceeded . Can someone guide here